# Easy way to distinguish between 0 and False in a dataframe with mixed values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe where the values take on either `1, 0, False` but the rows with `False` or `O` are functionally different.

I would therefore like to convert either the `False` or `0` values to something else

What would be an good way to do this?

Using replace has not worked well

`df["col_name"] = df["col_name"].replace(0,2)` converts the `False` values too

and

`df["col_name"] = df["col_name"].replace(False,2)` converts the `0` values too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) to replace values with a `boolean mask` - the advantage of this solution is **no** original `types` are changed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col':[1, False, 0]})

df['Col'] = df['Col'].mask(df['Col'].astype(str) == '0', 2).replace(False, 3)
print (df)
   Col
0    1
1    3
2    2
```

Solution with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dict`, but first converting to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) works too, but generally it convert all values to `str` what with real data can be problem.

```
d = {'0':'Zero', 'False':False}
df = df['Col'].astype(str).replace(d)
print (df)
0        1
1    False
2     Zero
Name: Col, dtype: object
```

I try create more general solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and checking `bools` by `isinstance`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col':[1, False, 0, True,5]})
print (df)
     Col
0      1
1  False
2      0
3   True
4      5

m = df['Col'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool))
df['Col'] = df['Col'].mask(m, df['Col'].map({False:2, True:3}))

print (df)
  Col
0   1
1   2
2   0
3   3
4   5
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's use `astype`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Datavalue':[1,False,0]})

df.Datavalue.astype(str) == "0"
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: Datavalue, dtype: bool

df.loc[df.Datavalue.astype(str) == "0",'Datavalue'] = "Zero"
```

Output:

```
  Datavalue
0         1
1     False
2      Zero
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert to str type and then use [`df.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
In [223]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Col':[1, False, 0]})

In [224]: df.Col.astype(str).replace('0', 'Zero').replace('False', np.nan)
Out[224]: 
0       1
1     NaN
2    Zero
```

Answer (score 3):

Use jezrael's dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col':[1, False, 0]})
```

**Option 1**
If there are only three values, 1, 0, or False, then being of type `bool` is as good as being `False`

```
df.Col.mask(df.Col.apply(type) == bool, 2)

0    1
1    2
2    0
Name: Col, dtype: object
```

---

**Option 2**
You can use the `python` `is` operator

```
False is 0

False
```

And use `mask` as we had before

```
df.mask(df.Col.apply(lambda x: x is False), 2)

0    1
1    2
2    0
Name: Col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Then that throws it off.  However, if OP is correct and only 3 values, then this works.